# zend framework 2 composer.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

when I try to install webino-image-thumb using zend php  composer it gave me this error

```
php composer.phar require webino/webino-image-thumb:2.*<br/>
./composer.json has been updated<br/>
Loading composer repositories with package information<br/>
Ignoring unknown parameter "server role"<br/>
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)<br/>
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.<br/><br/>



 Problem 1<br/>
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0, dev-master].<br/>
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0, dev-master].<br/>
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-admin 0.1.0 -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0].<br/>
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-admin == 9999999-dev -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-admin[dev-master].<br/>Any help<br/>Lanka
```

Comment: check your composer, json file see if the package you intend to load are same as the required plugin have that you want to load

Comment: Read composer documentaion https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `"webino/webino-image-thumb":"2.*"` by `"webino/webino-image-thumb":"1.*"`

`Composer` filters packages by stability and by default it requires a minimum stability of `stable`. You can change this to `RC` since `webino-image-thumb` is 2.0.0-RC1 at the time of writing this or just use the 1.* stable release. Check the doc [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability)

Comment: `Loading composer repositories with package information<br/>
Ignoring unknown parameter "server role"<br/>
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)<br/>
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.<br/>
  Problem 1<br/>
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0, dev-master].<br/>
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0, dev-master].<br/>
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-admin == 9999999-dev -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-admin[dev-master].<br/>Installation failed