# installing modules from git zendframework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

Is there any way to install modules by directly downloading from git-hub without php composer.phar. Because my php composer is not working.

this is the error

```
$ php composer.phar require webino/webino-image-thumb:2.*
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Ignoring unknown parameter "server role"
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

   Problem 1
     - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0, dev-master].
     - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0, dev-master].
     - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-admin 0.1.0 -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-admin[v0.1.0].
     - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-admin == 9999999-dev -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-admin[dev-master].


 Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{ 
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application", 
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2", 
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause", 
    "keywords": [ "framework", "zf2" ], 
    "minimum-stability": "dev", 
    "homepage": "framework.zend.com/", 
    "require": { 
        "php": ">=5.3.3", 
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.0", 
        "webino/webino-image-thumb": "1.*", 
        "zf-commons/zfc-admin":"0.1.0"
    } 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [zend framework 2 composer.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307370/zend-framework-2-composer-php)

Comment: check if you have ~/.composer/config.json

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can typically install Zend 2 Modules.

- Through the file system
- Git
- Composer

You could just run:

```
https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin.git
```

to get the module. But I am unsure if it is going to work since you likely have a dependency issue that needs resolving. I would recommend sticking with composer. Please post your whole composer.json file and I'm sure that the issue can be solved.

Comment: {
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.0",
        "webino/webino-image-thumb": "1.*",
        "zf-commons/zfc-admin":"0.1.0"
    }
}

Comment: how did you style your comments and posts

Comment: If you post that JSON in your question with 4 space indent it should be rendered with syntax highlighted and in a code block

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error.

I copy your `composer.json` file into an empty directory and execute `composer install` there. Works.

I then issue `composer require webino/webino-image-thumb:2.*`, and it downloads that version (2.0.0-RC1) just fine.

Comment: he have packages with conflicting versions for dependencies